# Attempting to change the BackColor of a Form by a button that is located on a seperate Form

Tags: c#

Title says it all.

but this is the code I used

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1();

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        {
            f1.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
```

For example, the button is on Form4, and when I click that button, I want the BackColor of Form1 to change to white, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you're creating a new instance of the class Form1 from Form4, and changing it's color. If you want to change the color of an already existing instance of Form1, you could pass the instance of Form1 to the constructor of Form4, and assigning that instance to a Form1 property inside of Form4, like so:

```
public Form1 MyForm1; //Form1 property.

public Form4(Form1 form) //Form4's constructor.
{
    MyForm1 = form;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

When you call Form4, you should pass the instance of Form1. If it's being called from Form1, you simply pass `this`:

```
    Form4 MyForm4 = new Form4 (this);
    Form4 .Show();
```

Finally, in Form4 you would have the click event:

```
private void btnChangeColor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyForm1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
}
```